# Connecting PCs with Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I want to write a programm where multiple clients  can join on a server. For now the clients are only able to ask for the servertime, which works perfectly fine, as long as the client and the server are on the same pc. I'm pretty sure that I have to change the EndPoint in the Connect() Method of the client, but I don't know what i should change it to.

Please help me to find a solution for this.

I have this code on my server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Multiple_Clients
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int port = 4567;

        private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];
        private static List<Socket> _clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";
            setupServer();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void setupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
            _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
            _serverSocket.Listen(500);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null);

        }

        private static void acceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            _clientSockets.Add(socket);
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), null);
        }
        private static void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
            byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
            Console.WriteLine("Text received: " + text);

            string response = string.Empty;
            if (text.ToLower() != "get time")
            {
                response = "Invalid Request";
            }
            else
            {
                response = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            }

            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
            socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(sendCallback), socket);
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), socket);
        }

        private static void sendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            socket.EndSend(AR);
        }
    }
}
```

And this on my client

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Multiple_Clients
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int port = 4567;

        private static Socket _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Client";
            connect();
            sendLoop();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void connect()
        {
            int attempts = 0;
            while(!_clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    attempts++;
                    _clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
                }
                catch(SocketException)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection attempts: " + attempts.ToString());
                }
            }
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        }

        private static void sendLoop()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a request:");
                string req = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);
                _clientSocket.Send(buffer);

                byte[] receivedBuf = new byte[1024];
                int rec = _clientSocket.Receive(receivedBuf);
                byte[] data = new byte[rec];
                Array.Copy(receivedBuf, data, rec);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to improve this question are welcome.
Thank you very much for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client allways connect to IPAddress.Loopback ... in fact the local IP Address 127.0.0.1. Exchange IPAddress.Loopback to the real IPAdress of your server, e. g. IPAddress.Parse("192.168.?.?") ...!

Comment: How exactly can i get the real IPAddress of my server?

Comment: you have to configure the dns name or ip address of your server on client side! the server could have multiple network adapters and ip addresses. see windows control panel -> network adapter -> details (TCP/IP v4) for example or use command shell (cmd.exe) "ipconfig /all".

Comment: I made it this far but i don't know what I should write there. [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/smnf7f6)

Comment: if you've executed the ipconfig statement on the server you should use the IP address 10.0.0.6 at the client side to connect to the server.

Comment: the server and the client are on the same pc, so yes i have executed the ipconfig on the server. Using IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.6") instead of IPAddress.Loopback results in the Programm getting stuck at this line whan debugging (without any error, it just doesn't do anything). But since i want to connect to my friends pc and not to a pc at my home I'm not sure if 10.0.0.6 is the right choice. Shouldn't i get a puplic id from somewhere?

Comment: then all things get more complicated, if you want to communicate over the internet and both - client and server are behind a firewall. if so, you've to determine your public ip adress (http://whatismyip.org/) and tell it to your friend(s) and you have also set up your router and firewalls(s) to accept incoming connections and forward them to your server computer.
i'm really sorry - in practice it is not an easy task. allthough there are other possibilities, but they require you to host a public accessible gateway.

Comment: It might not be an easy task but it is exactly what i need. I guess it would be too mach to ask you to write the code, but it would help me a lot if u had something like an example or a link to a description or anything like that.

Comment: if you have a fixed ip address from your internet service provider, you can host your server on your local pc and you've only set up your router and/or firewall - there is no need to code anything, it is just a configuration issue.
if you do not have a fixed ip address or it is not possible for you to change firewall/router configuration (because you are e.g. behind a corporate firewall) you need infrastructure - that means, a public accessible host, where you can run code, preferable c#/.net code to host "that" gateway. what infrastructure do you have?